# Identifying sections tabbed in from raw text

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, text-analysis

Consider the text on [this page](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2011/04/07/senate-section/article/S2241-1). If you look at the source code, you'll see that the main text is presented exactly as in the page -- no HTML divisions or any other way to obviously find paragraphs/tabbed in sections.

Is there a way to automatically identify and remove sections that are tabbed in from the raw text?

One thing I notice is that when I encode the text as `text = unicode(raw_text).encode("utf-8")`, I can then see a bunch of \n's for line skips. But no \t's. (This might be not a useful direction to think, but just an idea).

Edit: The following works

```
text = unicode(raw_text).encode("utf-8")
y = [x for x in text.split("\n") if "     " not in x]
final = " ".join(y)
```

Comment: I'd say `\n\s\s` is a paragraph section whereas a newline followed by more than two spaces is a tabbed-in section. RegEx seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking at the page, they are 'tabbed' in with spaces rather than the tab character; looking for tabs would not be useful.  It looks like the section is tabbed in with 5 spaces.

```
raw_text.replace('     ','')
```

To replace all occurances of 5 spaces...

```
from re import sub

...

raw_text = sub(r'     .*\n', '', raw_text)
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I should have noticed that. I suppose I can try to find the first and last sentences preceded by 5 spaces.

Ultimately, I want to delete all of the text that is tabbed in as such.

Comment: Then you can use Regular Expressions.  I will update my answer to show how that is done...

Comment: Ok, that would be great. I just wrote something quick that worked (not using re). I'll add it to my question, but accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your updated answer isn't quite what I wanted. I didn't want to just delete the tabs, but rather all text that is tabbed in (so any line that starts with 5 spaces)